# Unable to return a value from a protected value

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to create a game of Tetris as a pet project in visual C++. I created a class to hold each piece and in that class I have **protected variables**. When I try to create functions to be able to change and set those values I run into these four errors:

```
   expression must be a modifiable |value (on line 31)
   expression must be a modifiable |value (on line 32)
   explicit type is missing('int'assumed) [when i put in an int for that 
   function it expects an identifier] (on line 38)
   return value type does not match the function type (on line 40)
```

Here is my code:

```
class Tetris
{
protected:
    int x[4];
    int y[4];
    int ID;
    int piece;
    int rotation;

public:
    Tetris(int &x, int &y, int ID, int piece, int rotation);

    int getX();
    void setX(int &x);

    int getY();
    void setY(int &y);

    int getID();
    void setID(int ID);

    int getPiece();
    void setPiece(int piece);

    int getRotation();
    void setRotation(int rotation);
};

Tetris::Tetris(int &x, int &y, int ID, int piece, int rotation)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->ID = ID;
    this->piece = piece;
    this->rotation = rotation;
}

Tetris::int getX()
{
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Why do you define x as an array, but then use it as if it is a single item and not an array?

Comment: Lots wrong here -- you can't assign an array from a single value (`int x[4] = 1`).  You are trying to tell the compiler that there exists some type `Tetris::int` (which there is _not_).  You've not defined `getX()` as a member function (as in `int Tetris::getX()`)

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson that's how I learned it, you pass it by reference and you treat it as a single item if your trying to use the entire array instead of using individual elements in that array.

Comment: @TheAmericanFox you learned incorrectly.  You may be thinking about array decaying to pointer (`int x[4]` will decay to `int*` in certain circumstances)

Comment: an "int &" is just a reference to a single int, not a reference to an array.  Secondly, the implementation to getX should at least begin like "int Tetris::getX() {...}" not "Tetris::int".  Not that I even understand what you are trying to do with the confusion of your arrays.

Comment: i got it fixed i just needed to not be dumb

Comment: It's hard to tell which line of code matches each error message. It would be helpful if you mark the lines in the code.